# C# Process cannot access the file , used by another process.How to solve this issue?

Tags: c#, http, streamreader, xmldocument

I have posted the full code for reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace micro
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        // To generate the signature
        // creating an object for the class 'SamplePinpointSignatureGenerator
        Program microsoft = new Program();
        String applicationId = "****";
        Debug.WriteLine("The application Id :" + applicationId);
        String applicationKey = "*******";
        Debug.WriteLine("The application Key :" + applicationKey);

        //Debug.WriteLine("The requested URI :" + signs);
        // GenerateSignature(signs, applicationId, applicationKey);
        // To read the information from the CSVfile

        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Book3.csv"));
        //var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Book2.csv"));
        var listA = new List<String>();
        var listB = new List<String>();
        var listC = new List<String>();
        var listD = new List<String>();
        var listE = new List<String>();
        var listF = new List<String>();


        int linenumber = 0;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                linenumber++;


                String[] values = line.Split(',');
                if (linenumber > 1)
                {

                    if (values.Length > 1)
                    {
                        listA.Add(values[0]);
                        listB.Add(values[1]);
                        listC.Add(values[2]);
                        listD.Add(values[3]);
                        listE.Add(values[4]);
                        listF.Add(values[5]);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        String path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/pinpoint1.csv";
        var w = new StreamWriter(path);
        var line1 = string.Format("AdvertiserName" + "," + "BusinessNeedNumber" + "," + "IndustryFocusNumber" + "," + "Competency" + "," + "URL" + "," + "Signauture" + "," + "SignatureURL");// + "," + "State" + "," + "City" + "," + "Country" + "," + "UniqueId" + "," + "ProfileURL");
        w.WriteLine(line1);
        w.Flush();

        String[] firstlistA = listA.ToArray();
        String[] firstlistB = listB.ToArray();
        String[] firstlistC = listC.ToArray();
        String[] firstlistD = listD.ToArray();
        String[] firstlistE = listE.ToArray();
        String[] firstlistF = listF.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstlistD.Length; i++)
        {
            String a = firstlistA[i].Replace("\"", "");
            String b = firstlistB[i].Replace("\"", "");
            String c = firstlistC[i].Replace("\"", "");
            String d = firstlistD[i].Replace("\"", "");
            String e = firstlistE[i].Replace("\"", "");
            String fy = firstlistF[i].Replace("\"", "");

            String URLdata = d + "," + e + "," + fy;
            Debug.WriteLine(URLdata);
            Uri signs = new Uri(URLdata);
            //Debug.WriteLine("The requested URI :" + signs);
            String signature = GenerateSignature(signs, applicationId, applicationKey);
            String sig = signature.Replace("=", "%3d");
            String g = sig.Replace("/", "%2f");
            String f = g.Replace("+", "%2b");
            String q1 = String.Concat("\"", URLdata, "&sig=", f, "\"");
            String q = String.Concat(URLdata, "&sig=", f);
            Debug.WriteLine("BusinessNeedNumber :" + a + " IndustryFocusNumber :" + b + " Competency :" + c + " The URL :" + d + " : The signature URL :" + q);

            var data = string.Format(a + "," + b + "," + c + "," + signature + "," + q1);

            w.WriteLine(data);
            w.Flush();
            // Generate the XML file for information parsing
            String ab = microsoft.GenerateXML(q);
            // XmlDocument content2 = new XmlDocument();

            // content2.LoadXml(ab);

            //  content2.Save("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");

            ReadXMLfile(ab);

        }
    }
    public String GenerateXML(String q)
    {
        // Generating the XML file for reference
        // Getting the response in XML format from the URL

        Debug.WriteLine("The Http URL after URL encoding :" + q);
        Uri signs1 = new Uri(q);
        //Debug.WriteLine("The Requested URL for getting the XML data :" + re);

        WebRequest request1 = WebRequest.Create(signs1);


        HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();

        Stream receiveStream = response1.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        String ab = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        // Debug.WriteLine("The data :"+a);
        //XmlDocument content2 = new XmlDocument();

        // content2.LoadXml(ab);

        //  content2.Save("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
        return ab;
    }

    public static string GenerateSignature(Uri pinpointSyndicationRequest, string applicationId, string applicationKey)
    {
        if (null == pinpointSyndicationRequest)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("pinpointSyndicationRequest");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationId");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationKey");
        }

        //
        // Extract the path and query from the supplied URI
        // The hash should ONLY include the page and query (scheme, host, and port are omitted).
        //
        // e.g.,
        // http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners/?view=v2010.05
        //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //
        string request = pinpointSyndicationRequest.PathAndQuery;
        //Debug.WriteLine("The path and the query of the requested URI :" + request);

        //
        // Hash the path and query
        //
        string requestHash = GenerateHashBase64(applicationKey, request);

        //
        // Build the signature
        //
        string signature = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "S-{0}-{1}", applicationId, requestHash);
        //Debug.WriteLine("The signature :" + signature);
        //
        // The signature may now be appended to the URI (in the "sig=..." query param)
        // or included as an HTTP header (as "Syndication-Sig: ...").
        //
        // If the request is appended to the URI, it must be escaped first to encode
        // Base64 characters which cannot be included verbatim in the URI.
        //


        return signature;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a Base64-encoded SHA256 HMAC of the supplied string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key supplied to HMAC</param>
    /// <param name="content">String to hash</param>
    /// <returns>Base64-encoded HMAC of key and content</returns>
    private static string GenerateHashBase64(string key, string content)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
        }

        // Convert inputs to byte arrays
        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

        // Compute the cryptographic hash
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(contentBytes);

        // Convert to base64
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        //Debug.WriteLine("the base64 hash :" + result);

        return result;
    }

    // Method to read the XML
    public static void ReadXMLfile(String ab)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        XmlDocument content2 = new XmlDocument();

            content2.LoadXml(ab);

            content2.Save("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");// The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\direct.xml' because it is being used by another process.

            String path1 = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/pinpoint2.csv";

         using(var w1 = new StreamWriter(path1))
        {
        // Read and parse the required information from 'direct.xml'

            var reader1 = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");

            var xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(reader1);

            XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
            XNamespace metadata = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
            XNamespace dataservices = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

            var result = xmlDoc1.Root.Elements(atom + "entry")
.Select(e => new
{
    Title = (string)e.Element(atom + "title"),
    Id = (string)e.Element(atom + "id"),
    Urls = e.Elements(atom + "link")
        .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
        .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
            .Element(atom + "feed")
            .Elements(atom + "entry")
            .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
                .Element(metadata + "properties")
                .Element(dataservices + "Url")).Where(k => k != null)),
    City = e.Elements(atom + "link")
       .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
       .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
           .Element(atom + "feed")
           .Elements(atom + "entry")
           .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
               .Element(metadata + "properties")
               .Element(dataservices + "City")).Where(u => u != null)),
    State = e.Elements(atom + "link")
       .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
       .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
           .Element(atom + "feed")
           .Elements(atom + "entry")
           .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
               .Element(metadata + "properties")
               .Element(dataservices + "State")).Where(u => u != null)),
    Country = e.Elements(atom + "link")
       .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
       .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
           .Element(atom + "feed")
           .Elements(atom + "entry")
           .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
               .Element(metadata + "properties")
               .Element(dataservices + "Country")).Where(u => u != null))
});

            foreach (var entry in result)
            {
                foreach (var sta in entry.State)
                {

                    foreach (var ci in entry.City)
                    {
                        foreach (var coun in entry.Country)
                        {
                            foreach (var url in entry.Urls)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", entry.Title, entry.Id, ci, url);

                                String uniqueId = sta + ci + coun;
                                Debug.WriteLine(uniqueId);
                                // Writing onto CSV file
                                String advertisername = entry.Title.Replace(",", "&");
                                var data = string.Format(advertisername + "," + sta + "," + ci + "," + coun + "," + uniqueId + "," + url);

                                w1.WriteLine(data);
                                w1.Flush();

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            } w1.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting the following error

```
content2.Save("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");// The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\direct.xml' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have no idea how to solve the problem, new to c# programming, please help me out in the process. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you determined which process has the file open?

Comment: How do do that ? as mentioned new to c#.

Comment: @Sean : was able to solve it had to do w.Close() and w1.Close() and included 'true' in as -> var w1 = new StreamWriter(path1) and also return1.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the post it look like you don't have access right to the location. Or if there is already file with same name then it is being used by another process. You can't replace or delete the file being used.

Comment: How to get around this situation, any idea?

Comment: You can find out which service is using this file.

Comment: I did return1.close() and it did work. Now I want to append to the file rather than overwriting. How to do that any idea?

Comment: Append mode is that so ? do you know at least here how to do it?

Comment: FileStream readStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append); This may help you

Comment: I tried it did not work where to use in the code instead of var w1 = new StreamWriter(path1)?

Comment: :was able to solve it had to do w.Close() and w1.Close() and included 'true' in as -> var w1 = new StreamWriter(path1)

Answer (score 0):

At least for this issue I used return1.close() after w1.close().